# what is the lowest amount i can transfer using bitcoin ? can i send 0 satoshis?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

i was looking at this `bitcoin tx`

https://blockchain.info/tx/b4ea693a9d2d7e32b66777964fce13da302bed024bd9fd4651919da650fb1c40

where

```
Inputs and Outputs
Total Input 0.00003 BTC
Total Output    0 BTC
Fees    0.00003 BTC
Fee per byte    12.821 sat/B
Fee per weight unit 3.205 sat/WU
Estimated BTC Transacted    0 BTC
```

the user has set total output as `0 BTC` so in short all input is given as fee.

Is this common practice or bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unexpected (but valid) behavoiur of mining pool software. btw, i am creator of this tx

Comment: yes, 1aa... is my address

Comment: ~16 millions in "hot" (memory-only) database. welcome to email

Comment: alistermaclin@mail.ru please

Comment: got it. please delete comment.s,

Comment: could you explain, why it is unexpected? Isn't the tx valid? Or what is it, what makes it invalid, but gone through?

Comment: tx is valid but non-standard. pools have a right to confirm non-standard txs but usually do not use their ability.

Comment: i tried broadcasting similar tx but received error as dust tx. so how could you broadcast it ?

Answer (score -2):

rules are defined here: 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22tx.22_messages

it says "reject if the sum of input values < sum of output values", which is not the case. So a valid tx, where you spend all amounts to the miner...